# Two RecyclerViews are in sync and scroll smoothly, but load very slowly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have two `RecyclerViews` that I want to scroll vertically together. And one of them also has to be able to scroll horizontally. What I did to achieve this was put them in `ScrollViews`. To get the desired effect, I disabled `nestedScrollingEnabled`. They scroll together very smoothly, but I have a different issue now: the `RecyclerViews` load all views at once, rather than recycling views, which is taking a serious toll on the UI. I'm seeing frame skips of over 100 frames every time I want to display my RVs or change the data set in them. How can I better approach this?

Here's the XML. Please don't mind the width and height values, because those are set programmatically.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/verticalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headerConstraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/first_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/second_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting rid of the vertical `ScrollView` entirely, and used `scrollBy` to achieve synchronous scrolling. The `RecyclerViews` do their recycling properly now, and the problem is fixed!